# How do I create a persistence.xml file for JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, configuration, persistence.xml

I'm trying to use Hibernate JPA but I need to create my persistence.xml (so I can use the entity manager correctly). I am unsure of what to create and where to place it.

This is how my hibernate.cfg.xml in 'Core' mode configured.
I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE Web Developers (Indigo Release):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXXXXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://<hostname>/<database></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXXXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">XXXXXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: What kind of a project have you created in Eclipse? Is it a JPA project? If you created a JPA project, it should have a `persistence.xml` file.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds, my project it is a Dynamic Web Project in Eclips Web Java EE Developers, i didn't find it any persistence.xml file.

Comment: this post help me out :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703043/eclipse-turn-an-existing-project-into-a-jpa-project

Answer (score 18):

### JPA persistence XML file location

Traditionally, the persistence.xml is located in a `META-INF` folder that needs to reside in the root of the Java classpath. If you’re using Maven, you can store it in the `resources` folder, like this:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

### JPA persistence XML file structure

The `persistence.xml configuration file is structured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
 
    <persistence-unit
        name="HypersistenceOptimizer"
        transaction-type="JTA">
 
        <description>
            Hypersistence Optimizer is a dynamic analyzing tool that can scan
            your JPA and Hibernate application and provide you tips about the
            changes you need to make to entity mappings, configurations, queries,
            and Persistence Context actions to speed up your data access layer.
        </description>
 
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
 
        <jta-data-source>java:global/jdbc/default</jta-data-source>
 
        <properties>          
            <property
                name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="SunOne"
            />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The `persistence` tag is the root XML element, and it defines the JPA version and the XML schema used to validate the `persistence.xml` configuration file.

#### persistence-unit

The `persistence-unit` element defines the name of the associated JPA Persistence Unit, which you can later use to reference it when using the `@PersistenceUnit` JPA annotation to inject the associated `EntityManagerFactory` instance:

```
@PersistenceUnit(name = "HypersistenceOptimizer")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

The `transaction-type` attribute defines the JPA transaction strategy, and it can take one of the following two values:

- `JTA`
- `RESOURCE_LOCAL`

Traditionally, Java EE applications used JTA by default, which requires having a JTA transaction manager that uses the 2PC (Two-Phase Commit) protocol to apply changes atomically to multiple sources of data (e.g., database systems, JMS queues, Caches).

If you want to propagate changes to a single data source, then you don't need JTA, so the `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transaction type is a much more efficient alternative. For instance, by default, Spring applications use `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transactions, and to use `JTA`, you need to explicitly choose the `JtaTranscationManager` Spring bean.

#### description

The `description` element allows you to provide more details about the goals of the current Persistence Unit.

#### provider

The `provider` XML element defines the fully-qualified class name implementing the JPA `PersistenceProvider` interface.

> If you are using Hibernate 4.3 or newer versions, then you need to use the `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` class name.
>
> If you are using Hibernate 4.2 or older versions, then you need to use the `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` class name instead.

#### jta-data-source and non-jta-data-source

It's very unusual that the JPA spec defines two different XML tags to provide the JNDI `DataSource` name. There should have been a single `data-source` attribute for that since the `transaction-type` already specifies whether JTA is used or not.

No, if you're using JTA, you can use the `jta-data-source` to specify the JNDI name for the associated JTA `DataSource`, while for `RESOURCE_LOCAL`, you need to use the `non-jta-data-source`.

> If you're using Hibernate, you can also use the `hibernate.connection.datasource` configuration property to specify the JDBC `DataSource` to be used.

#### properties

The `properties` element allows you to define JPA or JPA provider-specific properties to configure:

- the Hibernate `Dialect`
- the JTA transaction platform (e.g., GlassFish, JBoss, Bitronix, Atomikos)
- whether the database schema should be auto-generated
- whether Hibernate should [skip the auto-commit check for RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-always-use-hibernate-connection-provider_disables_autocommit-for-resource-local-jpa-transactions/)
- [activate the slow SQL query log](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-slow-query-log/)
- and many more properties you can find in the `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings` interface.

#### Entity mapping settings

By default, Hibernate is capable of finding the JPA entity classes based on the presence of the `@Entity` annotation, so you don't need to declare the entity classes.

exclude-unlisted-classes

However, if you want to explicitly set the entity classes to be be used, and exclude any other entity classes found on the current Java classpath, then you need to set the `exclude-unlisted-classes` element to the value of `true`:

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

class

After setting the `exclude-unlisted-classes` XML element above, you need to specify the list of entity classes registered by the current Persistence Unit via the `class` XML element:

```
<class>io.hypersistence.optimizer.forum.domain.Post</class>
<class>io.hypersistence.optimizer.forum.domain.PostComment</class>
<class>io.hypersistence.optimizer.forum.domain.PostDetails</class>
<class>io.hypersistence.optimizer.forum.domain.Tag</class>
```

The vast majority of JPA and Hibernate applications use annotations to build the object-relational mapping metadata. However, even if you are using annotations, you can still use XML mappings to override the static annotation metadata with the one provided via an `orm.xml` configuration file.

> For instance, you can use the `SEQUENCE` identifier generator by default using the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation and substitute that with `IDENTITY` for MySQL, which does not support database sequences.

mapping-file

By default, the `orm.xml` configuration file is located in the `META-INF` folder. If you want to use a different file location, you can use the `mapping-file` XML element in the `persistence.xml` file, like this:

```
<mapping-file>file:///D:/Vlad/Work/Examples/mappings/orm.xml</mapping-file>
```

jar-file

Bu default, the JPA provider is going to scan the current Java classpath to load entity classes or XML mappings. If you want to provide one or more JAR files to be scanned, you can use the `jar-file` element, like this:

```
<jar-file>lib/hypersistence-optimizer-glassfish-hibernate-example.jar</jar-file>
```

#### shared-cache-mode

The `shared-cache-mode` element allows you to define the [`SharedCacheMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SharedCacheMode.html) strategy for storing entities in the second-level cache, and it can take one of the following values:

- `ALL` - stores all entities in the second-level cache,
- `NONE` - entities are not stored in the second-level cache,
- `ENABLE_SELECTIVE` - no entity is cached by default, except for the ones marked with the `@Cacheable(true)` annotation, which are going to be cached
- `DISABLE_SELECTIVE` - all entities are cached by default, except for the ones marked with the `@Cacheable(false)` annotation
- `UNSPECIFIED` - uses the JPA provider default caching strategy. This is also the default value that's used when the `shared-cache-mode` element is not set.

You can also override the `shared-cache-mode` strategy programmatically using the `javax.persistence.cache.storeMode` property, like this:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
.createEntityManagerFactory(
    "HypersistenceOptimizer", 
    Collections.singletonMap(
        "javax.persistence.cache.storeMode",
        SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE
    )
);
```

#### validation-mode

The `validation-mode` XML element specifies the [`ValidationMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ValidationMode.html) strategy, which instructs the JPA provider whether it should check the entities Bean Validation at runtime.

The `validation-mode` element can take the following values:

- `AUTO` - If a Bean Validation provider is found in the current Java classpath, it will be registered automatically, and all entities are going to be validated. If no Bean Validation provider is found, entities are not validated. This is the default value.
- `CALLBACK` - Entities must always be validated by a Bean Validation provider. If the JPA provider does no found a Bean Validation implementation on the classpath, the bootstrap process will fail.
- `NONE` - Entities are not validated even if a Bean Validation provider is found on the classpath.

You can also override the `validation-mode` strategy programmatically using the `javax.persistence.validation.mode` property, like this:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
.createEntityManagerFactory(
    "HypersistenceOptimizer", 
    Collections.singletonMap(
        "javax.persistence.validation.mode",
        ValidationMode.CALLBACK
    )
);
```

Answer (score 12):

Create a persistence.xml file that resides in the META-INF folder.

Example:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="sample">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
  <mapping-file>ormap.xml</mapping-file>
  <jar-file>MyApp.jar</jar-file>
  <class>org.acme.Employee</class>
  <class>org.acme.Person</class>
  <class>org.acme.Address</class>
  <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXXXXX</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://<hostname>/<database></property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXXXX</property>
     <property name="hibernate.default_schema">XXXXXX</property>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Another option is to set the packagesToScan property in Spring's config, like this:
<code>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>be.webworks.webshop.service.infra.persistence</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</code>

THen you do not need to keep a persistence.xml up to date or have it generated every time.

Comment: Attribute 'value' seems required in the xsd, are you sure this example is correct?

Comment: @KorayTugay This answer is three years older than your comment. They changed the syntax of the tags so, that value is nowdays required. :) `<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create" />` as example.

Answer (score 1):

In intellij, one good approach would be to just go to "File > Project structure > Facets".
Then Add new persistence.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml.
Click apply and it will be created for you.